# Yeoman Excel Addin - Certificate Issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, excel-addins

When trying to run the example from the Excel Addin Tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial#prerequisites), I get an error.

Inside Excel - Content blocked - there is no valid certificate

I also check at https://localhost:3000 and in fact, there is no valid certificate.

The npm start doesn't ask for the certificate installation. How can I do please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate (`ca.crt`) was in `C:\Users\%username%\.office-addin-dev-certs`.

Reference: https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/blob/master/src/docs/ssl.md#windows